# proper usage of C dummy functions replacement in different environment

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, function-pointers

I am trying to add test functions in a suite on both windows and linux machines. On linux machines i want the real functions to be added and on windows machine i want the dummy UnsupportedFunction to be added so that i can have same number of functions on both environments.

I have the following code

```
void UnsupportedFunction(struct1* test)
{
  //dummy function in C
}

// following functions defined else where and gets added only if its linux box
#if ENV_LINUX
extern void linuxOnlyFunc1(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc2(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc3(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc4(struct1* test);
#endif

static struct1* addTest(params, TestFunction fnPtr) {
...
}

static void addTestToSuite (struct1*     suite,
                    input   devices,
                    TestFunction testFunction,
                    const char*  testName,
                    const char*  testDescription)
{
  TestFunction  fnPtr = UnsupportedFunction;
#if ENV_LINUX
      fnPtr = linuxOnlyFunc1;
#endif
      LinWB_Util_AddTest(params, fnPtr);
}
```

the issue is since i have lot of tests to be added to the suite, i have to make an ugly if-defines on all the entries. To get rid of these i have to abstract with a function call but, those externed functions doesnt exist on windows env and i end up getting compiler errors or warnings (considered errors).
how can one design this in a better way ?

Comment: Welcome to the world of platform "compatibility". Even large projects, and even for code shared on platforms that should be compatible, the most common way to handle these things is with (potentially) big lists of preprocessor conditional compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like

```
#if ENV_LINUX
extern void linuxOnlyFunc1(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc2(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc3(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc4(struct1* test);
#else
#define linuxOnlyFunc1 UnsupportedFunction  
#define linuxOnlyFunc2 UnsupportedFunction
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, so it might need some tweaking, but you could do something like this:

```
#if ENV_LINUX
#define linux_only(x) extern void x(struct1* test);
#else
#define linux_only(x) inline void x(struct1* test) { UnsupportedFunction(test); }
#endif

linux_only(linuxOnlyFunc1);
linux_only(linuxOnlyFunc2);
linux_only(linuxOnlyFunc3);
linux_only(linuxOnlyFunc4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use include files to store your function declarations. Thus you dont't have to write them into every source file. And if the functions turn out to be undefined, just write such functions.

upon request, I elaborate.

You create a file called "fakefuns.h" which contains your function declarations:

```
#if ENV_LINUX
extern void linuxOnlyFunc1(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc2(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc3(struct1* test);
extern void linuxOnlyFunc4(struct1* test);
#endif
```

Then you can include these definition in every source file by adding

```
#include "fakefuns.h"
```

into the source file, preferably near to the first line. And in one source file, you actually implement these functions, both for Linux and Windows. And if they should not to any work in Windows, the implementations will be very simple.

Comment: could you elaborate on you idea ?

Comment: but how would UnsupportedFunction gets used for linux tests, on linux boxes where windows only tests run ?

Comment: The windows implementation can call, or be, UnsupportedFunction. That way, there is no need to mention the fact that it may be unsupported in every source file.

Comment: ok, i understand, yes you are right! but i need UnsupportedFunction to be added so that i can still see all the modules added with NAMES (later list all the tests on both windows and linux) on it :) thats y i was keen on wanting the UnsupportedFunction being added.